# How to display mySQL data in html using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

What I usually do is grab the data from the repository and pass that data along to the view via addAttribute, like this:

```
@GetMapping("html_page")
public String dynamicPage(Model model){

    List<MySqlDataDTO> mySqlDataDTO = mySqlRepository.findAllByName(name);

    model.addAttribute("mySqlDataDTO", mySqlDataDTO);


    return "html_page";
}
```

Then use thymeleaf to loop through the data and display it in a table, like this:

```
                         <table id="table" >
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Fav</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody >
                                <tr th:each="mySqlDataDTO : ${mySqlDataDTO}" >
                                    <th th:text="${mySqlDataDTO.id}"></th>
                                    <td th:text="${mySqlDataDTO.name}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${mySqlDataDTO.fav}"></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

This is all fine but, the issues comes up when the user intially sends the data to the DB, the page would refresh and force the user to the top of the page thus creating a negative user experience.

I figured out how to use ajax to fix the issue of the refreshing page by having the post request go through ajax first like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
        

        },
        error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
       });
    });
 });
```

Which works just fine by sending the data to the DB and not having the page refresh, but the issue is the retrieval of the data after its been sent to the database. I dont quite understand how to then retrieve the data and have it be displayed in a table to the user, here's what I have so far, but doesnt seem to work:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
         url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
         type: "GET",
         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             $('#table').empty();
             $.each(data.items, function(item) {
                 alert(data.name);
             });


         },
         error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert(errorThrown);
         }
       });
    });
 });
```

I added an alert just to see the data as a test. Basically I want to grab the data from the DB like I normally do via my repository, then pass that data to the view to be displayed like this: [image]

But again it should use ajax get, so as soon the user hits submit that table refreshes (not the whole page) and the table reflects the DB data.

Comment: Hi, can you show output of `data` ? Simply do `console.log(data)` you will see result inside browser console .

Comment: @Swati Data coming back as empty array